# wordpress function query_posts('showposts=3&cat=1') display 4 or 5 posts instead of 3. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to use wordpress function query_posts('showposts=3&cat=1') to display the latest posts  under category 1. But it displays 4 or 5 posts. Could you please help figure out the root cause? Thanks.

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=3&cat=17');?>
            <div class="n-placement n-widget w-image-text" data-type="image-text" id="u-aabm">
                <div class="n-inner" id="u-aabm-i">
                    <div class="w-image-text-container">
                        <span class="w-image-text-image" style="float: left; clear: left; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; margin-right: 6px;">
                            <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image();?>" height="112" width="112"/>
                        </span>
                        <div class="w-image-text-text">
                            <b> 
                            <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>-->
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                       </b>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <?php 
                                    if(is_category() || is_archive() || is_home() ) { 
                                        the_excerpt();
                                    } else {
                                        the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); 
                                    } 
                                ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: did you try this query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );

Comment: Hi Sismater, I tried just now, but it didn't work.

Comment: have you reset the query before performing your query?

Comment: Where is your opening `while`?

Comment: You have no loop - http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the loop after you define the query_posts().

So the code becomes:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=3&cat=17');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="n-placement n-widget w-image-text" data-type="image-text" id="u-aabm">
                <div class="n-inner" id="u-aabm-i">
                    <div class="w-image-text-container">
                        <span class="w-image-text-image" style="float: left; clear: left; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; margin-right: 6px;">
                            <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image();?>" height="112" width="112"/>
                        </span>
                        <div class="w-image-text-text">
                            <b> 
                            <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>-->
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                       </b>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <?php 
                                    if(is_category() || is_archive() || is_home() ) { 
                                        the_excerpt();
                                    } else {
                                        the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); 
                                    } 
                                ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```